# How to create a column scatter plot with data from two different pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, visualization, scatter-plot

I have a `1377 X 6` dataset that has 18 unique IDs, each with a value called `"foo"`. I split the `"foo"` column into `> 0.25` and `< 0.25`, resulting in two different dataframes.

I want to create a scatter plot with the greater_than and the less_than values being plotted side by side, that looks something like :

[image: plot]

How would I go about creating that plot if the two columns are from different dataframes?

Comment: How about posting some of the points used in CC "column" and in "MI" column? Those are clearly bivariate and some more information could be helpful.

Comment: This picture was just found online, it's not related to my data.
Here's an overview of what the data looks like:
18 unique IDs, with a 'foo' column on which I'm trying to use to plot the data. These 'foo' _values_ should be on the Y axis. On the X axis, there should be two groups: one with the > 0.25 values (red), and one with the < 0.25 values (blue). These two groups come from different dataframes, which is mainly why I'm having trouble fitting them into the same scatter plot
I'm not sure what you mean by the points used in the columns. Is what I'm explaining still not clear?

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you want. Try something like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'red' : [], 'foo' : []})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'blue' : [], 'foo' : []})

df1['red'] = np.random.random(30)*0.2
df1['foo'] = np.random.random(30)
df2['foo'] = np.random.random(15)
df2['red'] = np.random.random(15)*0.25 + 0.3


_, ax = plt.subplots()

plt.scatter(df1['red'], df1['foo'], color ='red', label = 'LT')
plt.scatter(df2['red'], df2['foo'], color ='blue', label = 'GT')
ax.set_xticks([np.mean(df1['red']), np.mean(df2['red'])])
ax.set_xticklabels(['LT', 'GT'])
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Cheers.

Comment: I've implemented this, and I'm definitely getting closer to the answer I'm looking for. In my code, I'm using the ID for the X and the foo values for the Y axis, which returns this: http://i68.tinypic.com/1490878.png
However, what I'm looking for is to group the blue points into one 'tick' of the x-axis and the red points into another tick of the x-axis, just like in the photo in the description. Any clue how to get there? Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: also, quick question, what does the _, ax assignment do here? it doesn't seem to be used later?

Comment: Sorry, in this old version of my code, I was using ax, but after I realized it was not necessary. I'll update the code with a new version. I think the result it's what you want.

Comment: Let me know if it is what you are looking for!